# File retrieval from AWS S3 to Node.js server, and then to React client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a need to retrieve individual files from Node.js with Express.js. For that, I have installed `aws-sdk`, as well as `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. I am able to successfully fetch the file by using this simple endpoint:

```
const app = express(),
      { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3'),
      s3 = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

app.get('/file/:filePath', async (req,res) => {
  const path_to_file = req.params.filePath;

  try {
    const data = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: path_to_file }));
    console.log("Success", data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
});
```

...but I have no idea how to return the `data` correctly to the React.js frontend so that the file can be further downloaded. I tried to look up the documentation, but it's looking too messy for me, and I can't even get what does the function return. `.toString()` method didn't help because it simply returns `"[object Object]" and nothing really else.

On React, I am using a library `file-saver`, which works with blobs and provides them for download using a filename defined by user.

Node v15.8.0, React v16.4.0, @aws-sdk/client-s3 v3.9.0, file-saver v2.0.5

Thanks for your tips and advices! Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should consider simply sending the client a pre-signed URL and let the client download the file directly from S3.

Comment: That's not what is requested by the client. What was requested is to create a proxy for the file so that the visible url would be from their server, not S3.

Comment: OK, well it's an option and one that you can hide behind a redirect e.g. the client requests `/api/getfile/xyz.jpg` and you respond with a 302 redirect to an S3 pre-signed URL. That aside, what's wrong with Express [res.sendFile()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)? Use the AWS SDK to download the file to your web server and then serve it from the download location. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally data from S3 is returned as a buffer. The file contents are part of the `Body` param in the response. You might be doing `toString` on the root object.

You need to use `.toString()` on the body param to make it a string.

Here is some sample code that might work for use case

```js
// Note: I am not using a different style of import
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const Bucket = "my-bucket"

async getObject(key){
 const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, key}).promise()
 if (data.Body) {return data.Body.toString("utf-8") } else { return undefined}
}
```

To return this in `express`, you can add this to your route and pass the final data back once you have it.

```
res.end(data));
```

Consuming it in React should be the same as taking values from any other REST API.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3861327/ravi-l)'s answer but caused a problem to display the image object in Frontend.

this worked fine:

```
  const data = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: path_to_file }));
  data.Body.pipe(res);
```